# Accessing a property of an alias in YAML

Tags: yaml, alias

I have the below code:

```
authenticationMethod: &authentication-method
  dev: 
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    additionalAuthenticationProviders:
      - authenticationType: OPENID_CONNECT
        openIdConnectConfig:
          issuer: https://tapendium.au.auth0.com
  uat:
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    additionalAuthenticationProviders:
      - authenticationType: OPENID_CONNECT
        openIdConnectConfig:
          issuer: https://tapendium.au.auth0.com

name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
schema: merged-schema.graphql
<<: *authentication-method.uat
```

How do I access the `uat` key as in `*authentication-method.uat`. The last line results in the error:

```
unidentified alias "authentication-method.uat"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the property an own alias, e.g.

```yaml
authenticationMethod: &authentication-method
  dev: 
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    additionalAuthenticationProviders:
      - authenticationType: OPENID_CONNECT
        openIdConnectConfig:
          issuer: https://tapendium.au.auth0.com
  uat: &u
    authenticationType: API_KEY
    additionalAuthenticationProviders:
      - authenticationType: OPENID_CONNECT
        openIdConnectConfig:
          issuer: https://tapendium.au.auth0.com

name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
schema: merged-schema.graphql
<<: *u
```

YAML aliases are always a simple reference to a node, they are not some kind of query language.